# What is tmux's "message-command"?

Tags: tmux

I've been trying to figure out how to change the background color of the command prompt in tmux's copy mode. It defaults to black on orange, at least on my setup.

I changed the color of the command prompt that lives in the status-line with these lines in my `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g message-bg '#e7e7e7'
set -g message-fg '#000000'
```

but this has no effect on the prompt that shows up above the status-line when, for instance, I run `list-keys` and hit `/` to search. The `Search Down:` prompt is black on orange.

I'd hoped I could change it with `set -g message-command-bg '#e7e7e7'` but no dice, and in fact, I can't figure out what `message-command-style` changes at all. The manual says it changes the stye of 'status line message command', but I have no idea what that would be, if not exactly what I changed with `message-bg`.

Any help?

*As requested*:
My `.tmux.conf`

```
# This seems to have no effect at all
set -g message-command-style bg=red
# nor does this
set -g message-command-bg red

# use UTF8
set -g utf8
set-window-option -g utf8 on

# 256 colors
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# reload config
bind R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded"

# scrollback history
set -g history-limit 3000

# act like GNU screen
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix

# indifferent bindings
bind C-n next-window
bind C-p previous-window
bind C-l last-window

# kills
bind-key k kill-pane
unbind &
bind-key K confirm-before -p "kill-window #W? (y/n)" kill-window
unbind x
bind-key x confirm-before -p "kill-session #S? (y/n)" kill-session

# shorten command delay
set -sg escape-time 1

# set pane color
set-option -g pane-border-fg colour240
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg colour240

# status bar
set -g status-utf8 on
set -g status-bg '#e7e7e7'
set -g status-fg '#404040'
set -g status-attr bright
set-window-option -g window-status-format ' #I #W'
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format ' #I #W'
set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg '#1922bd'
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright
set -g message-bg '#e7e7e7'
set -g message-fg '#000000'

set -g status-justify left
set -g status-right-length 50
set -g status-right ' (#S) :: #h :: #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d " " -f 3-5) '
set -g status-left ''
```

Comment: Can you please post your entire .tmux.conf?

Answer (score 6):

Knowing the version of tmux might help. Disregarding *packager's* local customizations,

- tmux 1.8 didn't do this at all.
- tmux 1.9a added three configurable settings using black/yellow,
- which are still in tmux 2.1 (a *few* features were dropped).

To see the details, read [`options-table.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/options-table.c):

- `message-command-style` (yellow on black)
- `message-style` (black on yellow)
- `mode-style` (black on yellow)

The one you're asking about is the second, `message-style`, which the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) describes

> **`message-style`** *style*
>   Set status line message style.  For how to specify
>   style, see the **`message-command-style`** option.

A few other settings modify parts of this style: **`message-attr`**, **`message-bg`** and **`message-fg`**

Answer (score 3):

See [these code](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/status.c#L762...L765), the `message-command-style` is **only** used to set display style for **vi command mode** in tmux command prompt. To enable vi mode you should add `set-option -g status-keys vi` in you .tmux.conf.

If you want to change style in copy mode, try window option `mode-style`.

Answer (score 1):

The status line message comand is the prompt that appears when you enter your prefix plus <kbd>:</kbd>.

Setting these colours will *not* have any impact upon the colour of the search prompt (which, by default, is a rather garish black on yellow and is not configurable, AFAIAA).

Answer (score 1):

I found this that maybe helpful.

```
# Command / message line
# START:cmdlinecolors
set -g message-fg red
set -g message-bg black
set -g message-attr bright
# END:cmdlinecolors
```

Remember to to the **:source-file ~/.tmux.conf** to reload the configure file.Or you can do the following binding.

```
# Reload the file with Prefix r
# START:reload
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"
# END:reload
```